# Drush error during adding an install profile as platform

Tags: aegir, drush

In Aegir, I add a platform with a buildfile:

```
core = 7.x
api = 2
projects[] = drupal
projects[profiler_drupal_base][type] = "profile"
projects[profiler_drupal_base][download][type] = "git"
projects[profiler_drupal_base][download][url] = "git@bitbucket.org:joachimroeleveld/profiler_drupal_base.git"
projects[profiler_drupal_base][download][branch] = "master"
```

I made an install profile which I pushed to the [my public repository](https://bitbucket.org/joachimroeleveld/profiler_drupal_base/src) containing a .info, .make and .profile file (and the .build file so Aegir can read it).

After a bunch of tasks Aegir succeeded running (including downloading Drupal; the first step of the build file), I get this erors:

```
Unable to clone profiler_drupal_base from git@bitbucket.org:joachimroeleveld/profiler_drupal_base.git.
Could not download platform using drush make. No platform present
```

Is something wrong with the structure of my repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to use the HTTPS-link instead of the SSL-link.

```
projects[drupal_development_base][type] = "profile"
projects[drupal_development_base][download][type] = "git"
projects[drupal_development_base][download][url] = "https://joachimroeleveld@bitbucket.org/joachimroeleveld/drupal_development_base.git"
projects[drupal_development_base][download][branch] = "master"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line for repository URL like this:

```
projects[profiler_drupal_base][download][url] = "git://bitbucket.org:joachimroeleveld/profiler_drupal_base.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a theme I have on bitbucket. Got it to work this way:

- Log into but bitbucket and navigate to the repository you're downloading.
- Navigate to Downloads>Repositories. Right click on the 'gz' link next to the branch you need and copy the link.
- Paste this into your make file:

  ```
  projects[dws2012][type] = "profile"  
  projects[dws2012][download][type] = "file"  
  projects[dws2012][download][url] = "https://bitbucket.org/joachimroeleveld/profiler_drupal_base/get/master.tar.gz"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution for me was however to use the https link.